# Loading saved params (a Pandas series) into a Statsmodels state-space model

Tags: python, statsmodels, state-space

I'm building a dynamic factor model using the excellent python package `statsmodels`, and I would like to pickle an estimated parameter vector so I can build the model again later, and load those params into it. (C.f., this Notebook built by Chad Fulton: https://github.com/ChadFulton/tsa-notebooks/blob/master/dfm_coincident.ipynb.)

In the following block of code, initial parameters are estimated with `mod.fit()` (using the Powell algo) and then given back to `mod.fit()` to complete the estimation (using the EM algo) using the initial parameters as `initial_res.params`. (The latter is a Pandas Series.)

```
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(endog, k_factors=1, factor_order=2, error_order=2)
initial_res = mod.fit(method='powell', disp=False)
res = mod.fit(initial_res.params)
```

I would like to pickle `res.params` (again, a small Pandas Series, and a small disk footprint). Then later build the model from scratch again, and load my saved parameters into it without having to re-estimate the model. Anyone know how that can be done?

Examples I have seen suggest pickling the results object `res`, but that can be a pretty big save. Building it from scratch is pretty simple, but estimation takes a while. It may be that estimation starting from the saved optimal params is quicker; but still, that's pretty amateurish, right?

TIA,
Drew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `smooth` method on any state space model to construct a results object from specific parameters. In your example:

```
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(endog, k_factors=1, factor_order=2, error_order=2)
initial_res = mod.fit(method='powell', disp=False)
res = mod.fit(initial_res.params)

res.params.to_csv(...)

# ...later...

params = pd.read_csv(...)

res = mod.smooth(params)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! This package is a fab contribution, btw.